# Subset dataframe by conditionally passing values to iloc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in a data frame (df1) that contains the number of columns I should subset in another dataframe (df2) before performing a calculation.

`df1`

|  | count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 9 |

`df2`

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 337 | 687 | 972 | 530 | 366 | 187 | 964 | 952 | 820 |
| 1 | 144 | 971 | 233 | 819 | 340 | 600 | 694 | 155 | 913 |
| 2 | 904 | 951 | 732 | 987 | 661 | 907 | 786 | 126 | 674 |
| 3 | 675 | 474 | 925 | 663 | 570 | 591 | 805 | 404 | 184 |
| 4 | 775 | 907 | 616 | 973 | 800 | 117 | 512 | 222 | 300 |

However, the number of columns used for the subset has a threshold/limit so I tried to write it like this:

```
df2['mean_6cols'] = np.where(df1['count'] >= 6, df2.iloc[:,:6].mean(axis=1), df2.iloc[:,:df1['count']].mean(axis=1))
```

So if `df1['count']` is at least `6`, I want to use the first `6` columns from `df2`, but if `df1['count']` is less than `6`, I want to use the value specified in the row.

Unfortunately, it results in the below presumably because of `df1['count']` inside of iloc.

> TypeError: cannot do positional indexing with these indexers

I did think of writing a for-loop and using the index variable to get the current value of `df1['count']` for each row, but it's not a practical solution since I have a lot of different combinations of calculations/dataframes to do this for.

Comment: Does df1 represent the number of columns to lookup? Each row in df1 represents the lookup for the row in df2? In other words, row 0 use first 5 cols, row 1, first 6, row 2 first 8, row 3 first 1,... etc ?

Comment: Correct, except any number greater than 6 is treated as 6. So for example row #2 still uses the first 6 only. I realize the conditional isn't completely relevant to the lookup itself, but thought it might be important context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy broadcasting to mask `df2` by `df1['count']`:

```
mask = df1[['count']].to_numpy() > np.arange(df2.shape[1])

df2['mean_6cols'] = np.where(df1['count']>=6, 
                             df2.iloc[:,:6].mean(axis=1),
                             df2.where(mask).mean(axis=1)
                            )
```

Output:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | mean_6cols |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 337 | 687 | 972 | 530 | 366 | 187 | 964 | 952 | 820 | 578.400000 |
| 1 | 144 | 971 | 233 | 819 | 340 | 600 | 694 | 155 | 913 | 517.833333 |
| 2 | 904 | 951 | 732 | 987 | 661 | 907 | 786 | 126 | 674 | 857.000000 |
| 3 | 675 | 474 | 925 | 663 | 570 | 591 | 805 | 404 | 184 | 675.000000 |
| 4 | 775 | 907 | 616 | 973 | 800 | 117 | 512 | 222 | 300 | 698.000000 |

Comment: I have a variation of this calculation that replaces NaN with 0 before taking the mean. Is there a reason why `df2.where(mask).replace(np.nan,0).mean(axis=1)` does not produce the right result, but `df2.replace(np.nan,0).where(mask).mean(axis=1)` does?

Comment: `mean` will exclude `nan` values but not `0` values. so `pd.Series([1,2,3,np.nan]).mean()` give you `2` while `pd.Series([1,2,3,0]).mean()` gives you `1.5`.

Comment: That's actually why I have two calculations that are so similar, but `df2.where(mask).replace(np.nan,0).mean(axis=1)` gives me the mean of all the columns in df2, as if the mask didn't happen.

Comment: I figured it out, I would have to do `df2.where(mask).replace(np.nan,0).where(mask).mean(axis=1)` if I wanted both functions to see it.